# Cannot Use Controller.User After Sign In

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Currently I'm creating an ASP.NET Core app that uses Identity.

I successfully built Sign In feature, with my code was made briefly:

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> SignIn(string email, string password)
{
    var result = new ApiResult();

    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email); 
    var signInResult = signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, lockOnFailure:true);

    result.Success = signInResult.Succeeded;

    return Json(result);
}
```

However, I couldn't use `this.User` in Controllers, also I can't get currently logged user.

```
m_currentUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User); // This cannot be accomplished
```

As I know, `SignInManager` sets automatically authentication data, What's wrong with this code?

I referred bunch of examples but nothing found any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync` checks whether the given password is valid for the specified user. But it doesn't perform the sign-in process, which ends up creating a user's `ClaimsPrincipal` and persisting it via a cookie. You should use `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` instead(this method also check the password use `CheckPasswordSignInAsync`) :

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Or manually complete sign in after  `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` :

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:true);
```